# Can't find Docker Compose network entry

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I am trying to communicate from one Docker container running on my Win10 laptop with another container also running locally.

I start up the target container, and I see the following network:

```
docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                                                DRIVER              SCOPE
...
f85b7c89dc30        w3virtualservicew3id_w3-virtual-service-w3id        bridge
```

I then start up my calling container with `docker-compose up`. I can then successfully connect my other container to the network via the command line:

```
docker network connect w3virtualservicew3id_w3-virtual-service-w3id w3vacationatibmservice_rest_1
```

However, I can't connect to that same network by adding it to the `network` section of my `docker-compose.yml` file for the calling container. I was under the impression that they both basically did the same thing:

```
networks:
  - w3_vacation-at-ibm_service
  - w3virtualservicew3id_w3-virtual-service-w3id
```

The error message tells me it can't find the network, which is not true, since I can connect via the command line, so I know it's really there and running:

```
ERROR: Service "rest" uses an undefined network "w3virtualservicew3id_w3-virtual-service-w3id"
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `network` you define under your service is expected to be defined inside the global `networks` section (same thing for `volumes`):

```
version 'X.Y'

services:
  calling_container:
    networks:
      - your_network

networks:
  your_network:
    external: true
```

Do you really have  to use a separate compose yml for your calling container? If both of your container interacts with each other, you should add them **both** to one and the same compose yml. In this case, you don't have to specifiy any network, they will automatically be inside the same network.

Comment: Thanks, the key piece I was missing was that `external: true` option. It's working now.

The containers are separate, because the target is a virtual service for testing that can be used by other containers.